# Send message in CloudHaskell from IO monad

Tags: haskell, cloud-haskell

I want to send message (Cloud Haskell) inside not Process monad.

```
anyMethod :: Handler ()
anyMethod = do
    ...      
    liftIO $ return $ do _ <- send pid (QnrMes q a)
                         return ()
```

Here pid is ProcessId.
Everything is compiled, but the messages do not come to the process.
Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: `liftIO (return x)` never performs any IO, regardless of what `x` is. `return :: a -> IO a` is an IO action which does no IO, so you achieve nothing by lifting it. Why do you think this should work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Maybe it'll be useful for anybody.

```
anyMethod ::App -> Handler ()
anyMethod app = do
    ...      
    (appMesSender app) pid (QnrAnswers questionnaire questionnaireAnswers)

data App = App{appMesSender :: (ProcessId -> UnitMessage -> IO ())
               ...
              }
```

In fact, I prepared the function in advance.